# Unable to click Enter key using 'KeyEvent.VK_ENTER' with Robot framework

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to upload a file using robot framework, the file path is getting written inside the search window but some times the **Enterkey** is not getting clicked.

Is there any other way for this or is this the issue with browser cookies ?? And i also tried clearing cookies but no luck. Please help me with this.

Code tried:

```
public void uploadFile (String FilePath) throws Throwable {

    WebElement upload = _driver.findElement(By.id("upload_btn"));
    upload.click();

    CommonFunctions.setClipboardData(FilePath);
    Robot robot = new Robot();

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
}
```

Comment: What is this webpage?

Comment: You are saying some times its not working.. may be try with some sleep before and after Enter key.. make sure browser is in active focus..

Answer (score 0):

Following is another way of uploading a file:

```
public void uploadFile (String filePath) {
WebElement upload = _driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']"));
upload.sendKeys(filePath);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`Robot.keyPress()` generates key press event for the currently focused element. Make sure your focus is correctly set just before generating the key press event and try again.